# Can't make jquery validate.js works

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to validate the contact form of my bootstrap website but I can't make it work.
If I use the code from this [demo](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/exemplo2/) it works but with my code I can't make it works.. When I click in the submit button it refresh de page and don't show any message of error.

Here's my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contact_form">

                    <div class="form-group control-group">
                        <label for="contact_name" class="col-sm-4 control-label">NAME: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control contact-focus" id="contact_name" placeholder="Your name *">
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group control-group">
                        <label for="contact_email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">EMAIL: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control contact-focus" id="contact_email" placeholder="email@example.com *">
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group control-group">
                        <label for="contact_company" class="col-sm-4 control-label">COMPANY: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control contact-focus" id="contact_company" placeholder="Company name">
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group control-group">
                        <label for="contact_contact" class="col-sm-4 control-label">CONTACT: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control contact-focus" id="contact_contact" placeholder="Your number">
                            </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group control-group">
                        <label for="contact_message" class="col-sm-4 control-label">MESSAGE: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <textarea class="form-control fixed_textarea contact-focus" id="contact_message" placeholder="What do you want to say to us ? *" rows="8"></textarea>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group control-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send Message" />

                        </div>  
                    </div>



                </form>
```

JS:

```
$('#contact_form').validate({

    rules:{
        contact_name:{
            required:true,
            minlength:2
        },
        contact_email:{
            required:true,
            email:true
        },
        contact_message:{
            required:true,
            minlength:20
        }
    },

    messages:{
        contact_name:{
            required:"Please insert your name",
            minlength:"Your name must contain at least 2 characters"
        },
        contact_email:{
            required:"Please Insert Your Email Address",
            email:"Please Insert a Valid Email Address"
        },
        contact_message:{
            required:"Please Write Your Message",
            minlenght: "Your Message must contain at least 20 characters"
        }
    }


});
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I don't get any error message, it simply doesn't work...
The idea is click on submit and if inputs are empty it shows the error message but that's not happening, it just refresh my page...

Comment: there is no error message in the console? If it doesn't work, it should have some sort of indication.

Comment: no, zero errors in console

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a link to the page you are having trouble with?

Comment: I'm just working in localhost

Comment: oh wait, add a `name` attribute to your inputs, and give it the value of its `id`. Such as `<input type="text" class="form-control contact-focus" id="contact_name" placeholder="Your name *" name="contact_name">`

Comment: OMG how can I forget the `name` ? Thanks :)

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `name` attribute to your inputs, and give it the value of its `id`. Such as

````
 <input type="text" ``` id="contact_name" ``` name="contact_name">
````

I think the validator selects the inputs by its name and not its id.